# Blazor WebAssembly: How to inspect eventhandler bound to html-element in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I am currently testing Blazor WebAssembly and try the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In the example project, there is one page (File: Pages/Counter.razor) where an button increases the value of an counter:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

We can see an `onclick` event is bound to button and executes the eventhandler `IncrementCount`. When I start this page, then the page inspector of Google Chrome shows me the following button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
```

Where can I see the bound event `onclick` and the eventhandler `IncrementCount` in Chromes developer tools for blazor?

For comparison: In the javascript-framework knockout.js can see the event and handler in the browser when I use the page inspector:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: function() { $root.IncrementCount(); }">
```

Regarding the Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I assume, that I cannot see the event and handler in the HTML-Element:

> The HTML markup and C# rendering logic are converted into a component class at build time.

But I hope there is there any other way to see the event and name of the handler in Chrome.

Comment: May be this can help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: the debugger seem currently not suitable because I use chrome as standard browser for my reading and web apps on my workplace, but accidentally the debugger currently allows only a single chrome instance.